# how to bind a descendant function to the top level parent object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bind

`this.site` is undefined in my example.

If I don't use the .bind() it refers to `.next` (its parent), not the top level object. Is there anyway to get `this` to always refer to the top level object `exports`?

```
var exports = {
    site: site,
    results: {
        next: function($){
            debugger;
            console.log('Site: ', this.site);
            return this.site + $('.foo').attr('href');
        }.bind(exports),
    }
};

module.exports = exports;
```

Comment: It's a literal, why not just use `exports.site` instead ?

Comment: Also, as this is Node a common way (maybe not very common, but how I often do things ?) to do stuff like that in exports is like this **http://jsfiddle.net/JAmVy/1/**

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `.bind` at that moment because the object is still being constructed and `exports` doesn't have a value yet (or at least not the one you want). You have to bind the function, *after* you created the object. i.e.

```
exports.results.next.bind(exports);
```

Or you restructure your code a bit and make use of the existing `exports` object:

```
exports.site = site,
exports.results = {
    next: function($){
        debugger;
        console.log('Site: ', this.site);
        return this.site + $('.foo').attr('href');
    }.bind(exports),
};
```

Or you simply use `exports` instead of `this`, like [adeneo mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847851/how-to-bind-a-descendant-function-to-the-top-level-parent-object/23847940#comment36699452_23847851). There is no advantage to use `this` over `exports` in your case.